# Encrypting custom header - WCF - WSHttpBinding - Message Security

Tags: wcf, security, encryption, header

I have an `WCF` service, which is configured in `WSHttpBinding`, using `security mode="Message"`, with `clientCredentialType="None"`. I'm adding an custom `MessageHeader` using `IClientMessageInspector` on `BeforeSendRequest` and i want to also encrypt it. Is it possible?

EDIT:
Currently I've added an custom asymmetic engine, which is encrypting, using certificate acquired by:

```
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="Custom" customCertificateValidatorType="CustomCertificateValidator.CustomCertificateValidator, CustomCertificateValidator"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and decrypting (certificate on server found by thumbprint) specific values, just before writing/reading them to/from header. Is it a good way to do it? Can it be done better?

Answer (score 0):

This could be completed by specifying a service certificate.  By default, the message security is implemented by using Windows credential.

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
```

So just we need to do is specify a service certificate for encrypting and signing.

```
using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService)))
{
    sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "cbc81f77ed01a9784a12483030ccd497f01be71c");

    sh.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready....");

    Console.ReadLine();
    sh.Close();
}
```

Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I think, that I'm using service certificate (added by behavior), please take a look on a part of my web.config and tell me if I'm wrong: <behavior name="custom">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="THUMBPRINT" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>

Comment: Ok, Just adding the service behavior to the service section is Ok.

Comment: I've added it, but header is still not encrypted - when I'm looking at communication via WireShark I can see not encrypted header

Comment: After a long search on the internet, it seems that there is no solution to complete the encryption of the SOAP message header. Regardless of which security mode I use, the SOAP message header could not be encrypted.

Comment: Please refer to the below link I searched, wish it is helpful to you.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a1077ea-c5df-4b6e-85f9-317c665f74ab/how-do-i-do-not-encrypt-the-soap-header-using-wcf-?forum=wcf
https://www.oipapio.com/question-407977